# Ways other than an iframe to pass parameter from php to asp.net

Tags: php, asp.net, session, iframe

I have an PHP Application.  If I have logged in that application I am trying to pass the parameter as querystring through an iframe to the asp.net page.

Is there any other way to implement other than using an iframe?

Comment: parameter is passed to let know the ASP.net application that you have logged in? or is i some other variable? you can also do a form post.

Comment: yes. want to let the asp.net application to know that logged in PHP. how can post the php form to asp.net? i am not clear abt what u said.

Comment: does that mean that I can simply pass on the querystring and fake a login in your asp.net application?

Comment: yes... when logged in php--> querystring to asp.net login ---> mainpage without requesting credemtials.

Comment: I am checking for a solution. In the mean time check this paid product http://www.cafesoft.com/

Comment: Hopefully this is a banking website? Also what is the url to your site so that I can um, review it.. :)

Comment: my site? - Confused! This is a banking website? Was that a question to me?

Comment: How s the authentication setup for the ASP.net webiste? Is it forms/ Can;t you just post the cedentials from PHP to ASP.net?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the PHP application submit data to your ASP application, it would be better if they could *natively* and *securely* share some of the data.

How?

Well, your goal is having one script tell the other that the user has been logged in, right?  In PHP, this is usually done by putting something in the `$_SESSION`.  Your ASP application can't read `$_SESSION`, though.  You'll need to use something else.

When the user logs in, create a *unique value*.  Maybe the result of [`hash_hmac`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) over some interesting data?  Whatever it is, it should be unique *every time it's created* and unguessable.  Don't throw in things like the user's IP address or the current time.

Save the unique value to a database table that both applications can read.  Also store other information that will help identify the user, such as her identifier (user_id or whatever you have on hand).

So, the PHP code that logs the user in has created this unique value and stuck it in a shared database table.  Now, the PHP application should forward the user to your ASP application.  Include the unique value in the request.

When the ASP application receives the request, it will look for the unique value.  If it's found, it can look in the shared table.  If the value is found in the table, it can then take whatever measures *it* needs to in order to mark the user as logged in.

Once the ASP application has logged the user in, then it should *delete* the unique value from the shared table.  The user can be forwarded to wherever she was going in the first place.

By making the key usable only one time, and only after a successful login in the PHP application, you'll reduce the possibilities of abuse by malicious or curious users.  All of the *important* information will be hidden in the shared database table.

Be warned that this is an overly simplistic implementation of "single sign on" and is full of caveats and edge cases.  While it might work for you, it might not be *the best* solution.  Given your question history, it looks like you've been struggling with similar issues for quite some time.  You might want to give some thought into using a slightly more "industry standard" SSO mechanism.  [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) is the 800 pound gorilla of SSO standards.  I normally wouldn't wish it on my worst enemy, but maybe it's the thing you're really looking for here.

Also, don't use iframes, they're *cookie eating disasters* in some browsers.

Comment: if both the application has different database. how will i proceed.

Comment: please let me know as yo guessed i am running out of time.

Comment: If the applications have no shared data, how are *logins* shared?  You are going to need to resolve that problem before you can continue.

Comment: i am just passing the user id from application1, that i have created in the application2 for this sake. to pass the user id i am using the IFrame.

Comment: So here's the thing.  Any old script kiddie that realizes what your application is doing can instantly use that mechanism to log in as *anyone else with no authentication*.  You need to establish a shared data source between the two applications over a channel that the application can trust.  Users can't be trusted.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..but data bases are different and sharing cannot be done at this point as both application are already existing one.As you reminded me in the other post.

Comment: @SVC If both applications exist and each has its own, separate database, you *cannot* do what you are wanting to do. Even if you could do it, you *should not* do it that way.

Comment: Indeed, you're going to need to perform registration of user accounts that don't exist in the target on demand.  That's a whole 'nother basket of *crazy*, but it's *totally* doable given the framework I outlined above.  Instead of polling a shared database when their one time use unique value, the ASP application would request all of the relevant data from the PHP application through a simple web service (nothing as complex as SOAP; send a POST with the unique value, get back JSON), *then* log the user in.